# convert [28,28,2] matlab array to [2, 28, 28, 1] tensor

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, tensor

I am learning `tensorflow`. After completing the `tensorflow` tutorial `MNist` for expert (https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros), I am trying to use the trained model to run inference.

- I made two `[28x28]` images and put them into a `[28x28x2]` array and saved `Matlab` file.
- Then I used `scipy.io` load the array into `python`.

  However, my network is expecting a `[2, 28, 28, 1]` tensor.

  How can I convert `[28x28x2]` array to a `[2, 28, 28, 1]` tensor?

Comment: tried to make the question more readable and highlighted points/steps taken so far. try to make your post readable so that you get proper replies rather than downvotes

Comment: You create the array in MATLAB and use it in Python. Do you want to do this conversion in MATLAB or Python? Please be specific, and tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, transpose the array so that *28x28x2* becomes *2x28x28*
(3rd dimension goes first, then 1st then 2nd).

```
arr = arr.transpose((2, 0, 1))
```

> Attention: you could have obtained the shape *2x28x28* by using `arr.reshape((2, 28, 28))`, but that would have messed up the order of your data. I used `transpose` because I believe you want `arr[0]` to be a picture, and the same for `arr[1]`.

Then expand the array so that you get that last dimension

```
arr = np.expand_dims(arr, -1)
```

An example with *4x4* instead of *28x28*:

```
>>> arr = np.empty((4, 4, 2))  # an empty array
>>> arr[..., :] = 0, 1  # first picture is all 0s and second is all 1s
>>> arr[..., 0]
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> arr[..., 1]
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> arr.shape
(4, 4, 2)
```

Now the transformations

```
>>> arr = arr.transpose((2, 0, 1))
>>> arr = np.expand_dims(arr, -1)
>>> arr.shape
(2, 4, 4, 1)
```